# THREE.Camera.prototype.lookAt</<() - What does the </< mean?

Tags: javascript, firefox, three.js, prototype

So I've been playing around with THREE.js a bit and noticed something strange:
In Firefox, when you open the developer console and type in `camera.lookAt`(provided your camera is called `camera`), it outputs `function THREE.Camera.prototype.lookAt</<()`.

Now I'm curious what the `</<`means and where it comes from, as far as I know these are not valid characters in JavaScript function names. So far I haven't seen or noticed this before. I tried to reproduce this, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are rules, according to which of FireFox gives `names` for anonymous functions to display them in the console and in the call stack. And function `lookAt` is [anonymous](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L262).

Open the code below in FireFox, then open console and type `nonymous`.

**index.html**:

```
<script>
     var nonymous = function() {
       return function() {
       }
     }();
</script>
```

**console result**:

```
> nonymous
< function nonymous</<()
```

More info:

1. [Nonymous: Function-Object Consumption Naming Algorithm Implementation](http://johnjbarton.github.io/nonymous/index.html)
2. Splash Wavefront 2011 Paper: [Naming Anonymous JavaScript Functions](http://code.google.com/p/querypoint-debugging/downloads/detail?name=NamingJSFunctions.pdf), by Salman Mirghasemi, John J. Barton, and Prof. Claude Petitpierre
3. https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/vm/Debugger.cpp#L7720
4. https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/doc/Debugger/Debugger.Object.md#accessor-properties-of-the-debuggerobject-prototype